# Trying to make timer read as 00:00:00

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a toString method that reads numbers as two digits. For example, the output of the timer is usually: 0:0:0. I would like for it to read as 00:00:00. Here is the code:

```
public String toString() 
{
String numberAsString = String.format ("%02d", hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

     return numberAsString;
}
```

When running I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
at TimeA.toString(TimeA.java:57)
at Relay.main(Relay.java:22)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to format a string as a number (`%02d`). 
Use something like this instead

```
String numberAsString = String.format ("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `String.format` [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is incorrect, we cannot add in between the format, instead we leave the placeholders and provide values seperated by comma (,) that's not how it works.

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes,seconds)
```

say if you have `hours =0`, `min = 0` and `seconds = 0`

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 0L,0L,0L)
```

this will give output `00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

It has to be:

```
String.format ("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

In your code, you are first concatenating hours, minutes and seconds (yielding said `0:0:0`). You need to either add the leading zero first, before concatenating. Or you can use the Format function.

The error message `d != java.lang.String` is, because `hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds` returns a string. And a string cannot be formatted with the number formatter.